# Reading unicode filenames using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I have a file with unicode filename : aγλώσ.txt in a folder "test". I am doing os.walk on this folder and trying to open the file but I get this error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\test\\a???s.txt'
```

Below is the code that I am using.

```
path = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\test"
for rootFile, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
  for filename in files:
    absolutePath = os.path.abspath(rootFile)
    fullFileName = os.path.join(absolutePath, filename)
    with open(fullFileName , 'rb') as f:
       #do something
```

I also tried using for `rootFile, dirs, files in os.walk(path.encode('utf-8'))`

**Update:**

I tried `rootFile, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode(path, 'utf-8')):` and before opening the file I did `fullFileName = fullFileName .encode('utf-8')`
This gives me the following error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\test\\a\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb3\xc3\x8e\xc2\xbb\xc3\x8f\xc5\xbd\xc3\x8f\xc6\x92.txt'
```

The actual file name is aγλώσ.txt

Comment: Your posted code does not match the error message, since you are adding the string `"root path"` to your filename.  Please post the actual code you're using.

Comment: where are you running this from?

Comment: You mean the code location or the IDE? IDE is Eclipse

Comment: You don't need to get the absolute path of rootFile every time. The first element of the tuples it returns will always be start at the path you passed into os.walk(). Since you passed os.walk() an absolute path, rootFile will always be absolute as well.

Comment: your file name would be recognized as a\xa6\xc3\xa6\xcb?\xa6\xd2.txt. ? in the name will cause IOError.

Comment: @m170897017 I have updated my question where I have pasted the IOError message.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fullFileName = fullFileName .encode('utf-8')` line you added. The Windows file APIs don't understand UTF-8, they use either UTF-16 or a locale dependent multibyte encoding.

Comment: "locale dependent multibyte encoding" most of Windows locale-dependent encodings are in fact single-byte

Comment: But not all, that's why I said multibyte encoding. Used loosely like this multibyte encodings includes singlebyte encodings. If your code handles multibyte encodings correctly it will also correctly handle singlebyte encodings.